# Iterate through boost multi_index with custom ordering

Tags: c++, boost, containers, boost-multi-index

I have a boost `multi_index` container with multiple indices. How can I iterate through the elements with a custom comparison specified when iterating.

For example, given that `Element::name` and `Element::index` are indexed by the `multi_index` container

```
bool myCompare(const Element &lhs, const Element &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.name == rhs.name)
    {
        return lhs.index < rhs.index;
    }
    else
    {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name;
    }
}
```

However, the iteration should not be limited to the case above but allowing any kind of order according to the indexed members of Element similar to the SQL SELECT ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a feature of the multi-index container.

However, you can easily create an extra temporary index:

```
std::vector<boost::reference_wrapper<Element const> > temporary(table.begin(), table.end());
```

Now you can sort that index named `ordering` by your custom comparison:

```
std::sort(temporary.begin(), temporary.end(), myCompare);

// iterate table in that order:
for(Element const& e: temporary)
    std::cout << e.index << "\t" << e.name << "\n";
```

> **Bonus**: You easily persist that ordering in a  `multi_index::random_accesss` index using `rearrange`:
>
> ```
> table.get<external>().rearrange(temporary.begin());
> ```
>
> (where `external` tags a random access index).

---

More notes:

- your predicate doesn't define a proper weak total ordering. It seems you might want to do this instead:

  ```
  #include <tuple>
  bool myCompare(const Element &lhs, const Element &rhs) {
      return std::tie(lhs.name, lhs.index) < std::tie(rhs.name, rhs.index);
  }
  ```

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d72605bf7398372)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>

struct Element {
    int index;
    std::string name;
};

#include <tuple>
bool myCompare(const Element &lhs, const Element &rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.name, lhs.index) < std::tie(rhs.name, rhs.index);
}

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

using Table = boost::multi_index_container<Element,
      bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::random_access<bmi::tag<struct external> >
      > >;

#include <iostream>
#include <vector> // for the temporary index

int main() {
    Table table;

    // generate 30 random records...
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(table), 30,
            []{ return Element { rand()%100, std::string(1, 'a'+rand()%26) }; }
        );

    {
        // temporary index:
        std::vector<boost::reference_wrapper<Element const> > temporary(table.begin(), table.end());

        // iterate table in the order specified by myCompare:
        std::sort(temporary.begin(), temporary.end(), myCompare);

        for(Element const& e: temporary)
            std::cout << e.index << "\t" << e.name << "\n";

        // now to rearrange a random-access index on the multi-index container:
        table.get<external>().rearrange(temporary.begin());
    }
}
```

Prints (e.g.)

```
98  a
21  b
93  b
15  c
56  d
62  d
62  d
67  d
91  e
84  f
62  g
49  h
11  i
40  k
29  l
29  m
63  o
86  q
67  r
69  r
77  r
90  r
82  s
93  s
22  w
83  w
96  x
11  y
13  y
72  y
```

You can see, where names are equal, the lower index comes first.

---

**UPDATE** To the comment:

> *Hmm? Are you asking for magic fairy dust?*

Are you asking for magic fairy dust? There's no magic.

DBMS's don't use anything out of the ordinary. They typically use BTrees, very similar to the datastructures that underly your garden
variety `std::map`, or indeed the `bmi::ordered_[non_]unique` indices. So in this respect Boost MultiIndex is (close to) what you want,
already.

The main *addition* thing RDBMS-es bring to the table is persistency. With that, everything becomes more useful, more scalable and ... less
efficient.

> So, don't look at DBMS-es for the holy grail of efficiency.

There's a reason that in-memory key-value data-stores are widely employed for performance. Another important note is that retrieving an
ordered resultset in SQL does not perform well at all, ***unless the indexes already exist***.

Now, if you want the best possible performance, you might want to devise your own data structures (perhaps with the help of Boost
Intrusive), but seeing the level at which you pose these questions, I'd play with Boost Multi Index for an extended period of time before
you do. Just create the indexes you may sometimes need to combine, and write some "loopy code" ¹ that combines them as required.

### IDEAS

**Now** thinking out of the box, you *might* be wondering how you would "easily" implement the two-level ordering in a way that a DBMS
engine might.

1. Like the DBMS engine, the easiest thing would be to have an always-uptodate index at the ready:
   **[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c829dd784c1ebb5)**

   ```
   using Table = boost::multi_index_container<Element,
       bmi::indexed_by<
           bmi::sequenced<bmi::tag<struct insertion_order> >,
           // ready made index for traversal in composite order
           bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct readymade>, 
               bmi::composite_key<Element,
                   bmi::member<Element, std::string, &Element::name>,
                   bmi::member<Element, int, &Element::index> 
               >
           >
       > >;

   int main() {
       // generate 30 random records...
       Table table;
       std::generate_n(back_inserter(table), 30, []{ return Element { rand()%100, std::string(1, 'a'+rand()%26) }; });

       // effectively "zero" cost iteration there:
       for(Element const& e: table.get<readymade>())
           std::cout << e.index << "\t" << e.name << "\n";
   }
   ```

   Note that you can use *ordered composite indices* in Boost MultiIndex partially, too:

   ```
       for(Element const& e: boost::make_iterator_range(table.get<readymade>().equal_range("y")))
           std::cout << e.index << "\t" << e.name << "\n";
   ```

   prints (for the same random seed as above):

   ```
   11  y
   13  y
   72  y
   ```
2. Alternatively, you could have separate indexes defined, and use them with your own algorithm to achieve the two-level ordering:

   ```
   using Table = boost::multi_index_container<Element,
       bmi::indexed_by<
           bmi::sequenced<bmi::tag<struct insertion_order> >,

           // separate indices that we might combine in some way later::
           bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct by_index>, bmi::member<Element, int, &Element::index> >,
           bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<struct by_name>,  bmi::member<Element, std::string, &Element::name> >
       > >;
   ```

   Now combining the indexes becomes the job of the "engine" or, in this case your algorithm. Here's an idea:

   ```
   template <typename Index1, typename Index2, typename Table, typename Function>
       void SelectOrderBy2(Table const& table, Function function) {

           using T = typename Table::value_type const;
           auto& idx1 = table.template get<Index1>();
           auto& idx2 = table.template get<Index2>();

           auto it = idx1.begin(), end = idx1.end();

           while (it!=end) {
               auto next = idx1.upper_bound(idx1.key_extractor()(*it));

               std::set<boost::reference_wrapper<T>, typename Table::template index<Index2>::type::value_compare>
                   set(idx2.value_comp());

               while (it != next)
                   set.insert(set.end(), boost::cref(*it++));

               for (auto& e: set)
                   function(e);
           }
       }
   ```

   That's some pretty high-falluting template code, but you can use it quite simply:

   ```
   SelectOrderBy2<by_name, by_index>(
           table, 
           [](Element const& e) { std::cout << e.index << "\t" << e.name << "\n"; }
       );
   ```

   See it **<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>** too

---

¹ perhaps better referred to as generic/special-purpose algorithms ... :)

Comment: Although not exactly what I was looking for, however, this is really useful. Any idea if any container has efficient index based sorting like most DBMS?

Comment: Let me rephrase my comment. Any idea if any container has index based sorting the way most DBMS provide and is also efficient? Anyways thanks for the information.

Comment: I have expanded the answer (went a little bit overboard too). I hope you find the confirmation you need. And, in all likelihood you just want Boost `multi_index_container` with some (composite) indexes. Good luck!

Comment: Here's a link to a part of the livestreamed session: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/multiindex-ordering-by-combined-indices-1/ ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: How is `myCompare` an invalid predicate? It seems to meet the 4 invariants of strict weak ordering.

Comment: @SaifUrRehman You're right. I misread that apparently. You can disregard that part (although the tuple comparison by tied references trick is quite nice to know)

Comment: Yeah no doubt about the tie function however only useful if all values are to be compared by the same less or greater function

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @sehe's answer, if you really want to have fast access to *any* combination of attributes, this can be done with some metaprogramming and a little combinatorics, as shown in [this example](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2008/11/multiattribute-querying-with.html). Generally speaking, if you have *N* attributes *C*(*N*,floor(*N*/2)) indices are required (*C*(*a*,*b*) stands for [*a* choose *b*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html)): for instance to deal with 4 attributes you have to define 6 different indices. This only covers equality queries, not ranges like *a*<5 or 10<*a*<=12.

Comment: I actually wrote a lil bit on this concept using templated functions however I have about 8 fields and while writing I realized that I would need much more than 8 indexes to have any possible order. So I settled on using std::partial_sort.

Comment: Yep, for 8 fields you'd need 80 indices, by all means impracticable.